# Given a vector subspace $W$, there exist a functional f such that $W= \ker(f)$?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given $V$ a vector space of finite dimension over a field $F$, and given a subspace of $V$, say, $W\leq V$, I want to find a functional $f\colon V \rightarrow F$ such that $\ker(f) = W$ I don't know how to construct such a functional or if this is possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The kernel of a non-zero functional is necessarily of codimension $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ *of codimension $1$*, there is always a functional on $V$ whose kernel is $W$.

In fact, let $\{w_1, \ldots, w_{n-1}\}$ be a basis of $W$ and extend it to a basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ of $V$. Then define $f \colon V \to \mathbb{F}$ as $f(w_i)=0$ for $i=1, \ldots, n-1$ and $f(w_n)=1$.

This construction also shows that if $f$ and $g$ are two non-zero functionals on $V$ such that $\ker f = \ker g$, then there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}^*$ such that $g = \lambda f$.